running into many problems with jupyter notebook anaconda/conda commands and package installations
Background: I'm on MacOS M1 14.1.1 (23B81). I regularly use Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator to do small projects in data science/ML. I'm very unfamiliar with terminal-related stuff and environments so I always just launch Jupyter Notebook from the Navigator. I've had no problems at all before, but today I wanted to use TensorFlow so I tried to install it in a notebook cell with "! pip install tensorflow" but when I tried importing it, the kernel kept dying. So I looked at several questions on StackOverflow and github issues and stuff but nothing is working.

Most conda commands I do in the terminal ("conda install anaconda", "conda update --all," etc) end as shown in the image (starts with something about json metadata, then solving environment, then this error, then gets stuck on solving environment). Previously, when installing packages, I always ran "! pip install package" in a notebook cell, and after some research, I realized that it's not good to mix pip and conda? Again, I am very unfamiliar with what conda actually is, I always just use the navigator and Jupyter Notebook.
What should I do now? Should I just completely get rid of anaconda and install again? If I do that, what's the proper way to install packages like tensorflow so I can use it in Jupyter Notebooks? Or is there something better than anaconda?
